# How to validate an email domain address to display certain items to display in the drop down list menu when user inputs an email?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, linq-to-sql

I am working on a site where employees have a gmail or yahoo email and this determines the types of phones they get. If they entered a gmail account certain types of phones(iphones, galaxy, Samsung, etc) should appear in the drop down list. The same should work for yahoo account. There are more phone types for gmail accounts than yahoo accounts. I got the text box and drop down box to work. However, I need help writing a function to tell the difference between gmail or yahoo to determine what types of phones to display when user inputs email domain. Not sure if I need to do a switch statement or regex match.

Controllers code is below:

```
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,50})+(@gmail|@GMAIL|@YAHOO|@yahoo)+(\.)+(com|COM)$", 
      ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Format. Use: username@gmail.com or username@yahoo.com")]

[Required(ErrorMessage="Please input gmail or yahoo")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

view code is below:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, 
          new { htmlAttributes = 
                new { 
                      @class = "form-control", 
                      @placeholder = "Email@gmail.com or Email@yahoo.com", 
                      data_bind = "value: Request.Email", 
                      data_toggle = "tooltip", 
                      data_placement = "top",
                      title = "Requestor's Email" } 
    })

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

dropdowncascade.js //Getting information from user input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Carriers").change(function () {
    var carrierId = $(this).val();
    var emailAddress = $("#Email").val();
    $.getJSON("../Home/LoadPhonesByCarrierId", { carrierid: carrierId, emailaddress: emailAddress }, //reads what carrier id and the email from the user input
           function (phonesData, accsData) {
               var select = $("#Phones");
               select.empty();
               select.append($('<option/>', {
                   value: 0,
                   text: "Select a Phone"
               }));
               $.each(phonesData, function (index, itemData) {
                   select.append($('<option/>', {
                       value: itemData.Value,
                       text: itemData.Text
                   }));
               });
           });
});
```

Help with Function in HomeControllers.cs! //Needs to match the email domain to determine what phone types to display in the dropdownlist.

```
           public JsonResult LoadPhonesByCarrierId(string carrierid, string email)
    {
      //  string Email = txt.Text;
        //The email difference swicth statement
        //if(Regex.IsMatch(Email, @"^([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,50})(@gmail|@GMAIL)(\.)(com|COM)$"))
        string pattern = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,50})(@gmail|@GMAIL)(\.)(com|COM)$";
       string input = "mvilleda@gmail.com";
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
          if  (match.Success)
        {
            var com = from c in db.Phones
                      where c.CommerceAllowed == true
                      select c;

        }
           else
        {
            var gov = from g in db.Phones
                         where g.GovAllowed == true
                          select g;
        }

        var phonesList = this.GetPhones(Convert.ToInt32(carrierid));
        var phonesData = phonesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.Name,
            Value = m.PhoneID.ToString(),
        });
        return Json(phonesData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       public JsonResult LoadPhonesByCarrierId(string carrierid, string emailaddress)
       {
        string pattern = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,50})(@gmail|GMAIL)(\.)(com|COM)$";
        Match match = Regex.Match(emailaddress, pattern);//checks the email address from user and pattern.
        if (match.Success)//if true it will do the following
        {
                      var gov = from g in db.Phones
                      where g.GovAllowed == true
                      select g;
        }
        else
        {
                      var com = from c in db.Phones
                      where c.CommerceAllowed == true
                      select c;
        }


    var phonesList = this.GetPhones(Convert.ToInt32(carrierid));
    var phonesData = phonesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = m.Name,
        Value = m.PhoneID.ToString(),
    });
    return Json(phonesData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what's the critical point here... First, assume that the e-Mail pattern is already checked, so the only thing you want to check are the domains. A very robust way to do it would be to check lists of domains, which you would store in the Database / DB Context.

If you want a simple, quick and dirty solution, create two lists, and check them.

```
    var eMailProviders = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();

    eMailProviders.Add(1, new []{ "gmail.com", "googlemail.com" });
    eMailProviders.Add(2, new []{ "yahoo.com", "yahoomail.com" }); // I don't know the domains...

    var email = "something754849@gmail.com";

    var providerId = eMailProviders
        .Where(x => x.Value.Any(domain => email.EndsWith(domain)))
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(providerId);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JcVlym)

Or did I get the problem wrong? Of course, this is a hardcoded solution, but you get the Idea, this could be transported to your Database. Also, you could try to make Regex-based decisions, but why bother? it's easy to mess that up the Regex, and hard to reflect all domain options.

Comment: I don't have a database for emails. I need to figure out how I  can  write a regular expression in a switch statement or if-else statement. If that is even possible with regular expressions. In the controllers view I'm using a regular expression to determine if it is a valid email address. So, in the homecontrollers.cs file I need it to check if it's a yahoo or gmail domain and it will go to the database and gather the types of phones to display.

Comment: @Sandy25: You're missing the point of this answer. This would be an alternative to using the `[RegularExpression]` attribute. Which is a poor use of the attribute anyways. It's meant to validate a general format, not content. Regardless, with the answer here, you could easily validate that the address ends with a configurable list of valid domains (in case you need to add more later). You then simply need to add an error manually to `ModelState` via `ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Invalid email provider.")`.

Comment: You could even take this further by creating a custom validation attribute that provides this validation.